# Define a constant globally using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the best practice for importing a constant globally in my vue project, in my case it's an ENUMS.

I saw a solution by adding it in the instance of Vue like that

```
import { Type } from './models/Type.js'

new Vue({
  router,
  Type,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` is reserved keyword you could use another name like `myConst` and based on this [`tip`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) try  :

```
Vue.prototype.$myConst=4;

new Vue({
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
   }).$mount('#app')
```

and refer to it everywhere in your app using `this.$myConst`.

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.prototype.$myConst=4444;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

created(){
console.log(this.$myConst)
}
  
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <h1>test : {{this.$myConst}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Well i change the name but if i log the myConst it's still undefined, in my case i import the const from a different file

Comment: sorry i missed to add $ above